# Strange generic function appear in view controller after converting to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my project, after converting to swift 3, a new function appeared before my `ViewController` class:

```
fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
   switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```

What does this function do? Why do I need it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That is interesting. Before the latest Swift 3, you could
compare *optional* values, for example

```
let a: Int? = nil
let b: Int? = 4

print(a < b) // true
```

and `nil` was considered less than all non-optional values.

This feature has been removed ([SE-0121 – Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)) and the above code would fail to compile
in Xcode 8 beta 6 with

```
error: value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Apparently, the Swift migrator solves that problem for you by
providing a custom `<` operator which takes two optional operands
and therefore "restores" the old behavior.

If you remove that definition then you should see where the
comparison is done in your code. Then try to update your code
and remove the optional comparisons.

Comment: So that basically means in most cases I can simply remove it? I don't need to compare nil to optionals.

Comment: @BrightFuture: In my experience, Xcode adds that only if it is needed somewhere. Try to remove it and see what happens.