# Swift3 optionals chaining in IF conditions bug?

Tags: swift, swift3

This code worked just fine in Swift 2.3 and I don't understand why I have to unwrap `TestClass` to check if number is bigger than 4. This is whole point of chaining optionals, to save additional call.

Now to make this work, I have to check if `testClass != nil` (or use implicit unwrap with `if let` statement) and then check count.

Is this really the only way?

```
import UIKit

class testClass
{
    var optionalInt:Int?
}

var test:testClass?

if test?.optionalInt > 4
{

}
```

Comment: Sorry about the bad news on this one, but very glad you asked about it, as this is liable to come up a lot in one form or another.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251005/strange-generic-function-appear-in-view-controller-after-converting-to-swift-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional comparison operators are removed from Swift 3.
[SE-0121](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)

You need to write something like this:

```
if test?.optionalInt ?? 0 > 4
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bug. It is, alas, intentional. Implicit unwrapping of optionals in comparisons (`>`) has been removed from the language.

So, the problem now is that what's on the left side of the `>` is an Optional, and you can no longer compare that directly to `4`. You have to unwrap it and get an Int, one way or another.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, where are you initialising your `test` var? Of course it'll be nil if you don't give it a value!

And regarding optional chaining, what's the issue writing :

```
if let optionalInt = test?.optionalInt, optionalInt > 4
{

}
```

As always, safety > brevity.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen on Guard statement.
Example:

```
var playerLevels = ["Harry": 25, "Steve": 28, "Bob": 0]
```

for (playerName, playerLevel) in playerLevels {

```
guard playerLevels > 0 else {//ERROR !!
    print("Player \(playerName) you need to do the tutorial again !")
    continue
}

print("Player \(playerName) is at Level \(playerLevels)")
```

}