# Why wont this conditional work in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Hey prior to Swift 3 I previously used :

```
if CustomUser.sharedInstance.numberOfCredits > 0 {
}
```

Where `numberOfCredits` is `Double?`. Now I get the error: ***Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Int'***. Why is this? So I change 0 to 0.0 and get ***Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Double'***. Why doesn't this line work in Swift 3?

Comment: Can you display your shared instance and function? May be there is problem of optionals.

Comment: try this: `if CustomUser.sharedInstance.numberOfCredits! > 0.0`

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427736/6541007).

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work because your `numberOfCredits` is an `Optional` (`Double?`). Should be: [0121 Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md).

Do it like this:

```
if let v = CustomUser.sharedInstance.numberOfCredits, v > 0 {
}
```

P.S.: Apart from that: `numberOfCredits` sounds like it should be an `Int`, not a `Double`? And maybe it shouldn't be an `Optional` either - if there are no credits, it should be `0`? Hard to say w/o knowing what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 has removed comparisons between an optional and a non-optional with the same base type. You have three options to handle this:

- Explicitly unwrap the value with `!` if you know that it is non-`nil`,
- Use `if let` construct to unwrap the optional,
- Use `nil` coalescing operator

Here is how you can use the third option:

```
if CustomUser.sharedInstance.numberOfCredits ?? 0 > 0 {
}
```

**Note:** There is a possibility that `numberOfCredits` is optional by omission - for example, because `sharedInstance` is defined as optional without automatic unwrapping. In this case it is better to fix the underlying problem, rather than using `??` or `!` as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct CustomerUser {
  static var sharedInstance = Instance()
}

struct Instance {
  var numberOfCredits: Double?
}

let credits = CustomerUser.sharedInstance.numberOfCredits ?? 0.0

if credits > 0 {
  print("credits greater than zero")
}
```

---

**numberOfCredits** is an **Optional Double** (Double?) means it may contain a **nil** or a **Double value**.

That's why compiler wouldn't know what to do if **numberOfCredits** were nil.

```
if CustomUser.sharedInstance.numberOfCredits > 0 // wtf
```

In order to convert **Double?** to **Double**, you might use the **??** operator which not only will convert in case **numberOfCredits** contains a Double value but in case **numberOfCredits** contains nil will return 0.0, how cool that is?

```
let credits = CustomerUser.sharedInstance.numberOfCredits ?? 0.0
```