# Binary operators with optionals in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have lots of code in my project of this style:

```
let hasQuestionsRemaining = user.numberOfCredits > 0.0
```

where `numberOfCredits` is a `Double?`. So I get the error : `Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Double'`.

So now I use:

```
var hasQuestionsRemaining = false
if let numberOfCredits = user.numberOfCredits, numberOfCredits > 0.0 {
   hasQuestionsRemaining = true
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427650/swift3-optionals-chaining-in-if-conditions-bug.

Comment: `let hasQuestionsRemaining = user.numberOfCredits! > 0.0`

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil No. Most certainly don't force unwrap.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.2, you used to be able to compare Optional and non-Optional types directly, but that behaviour has been removed in Swift 3.0. You can read more about it in [proposal SE-0121.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)

Swift 3.0 leaves it to developers to handle their optionals in a way that's most appreciate to their application. In your case, this seems like the way to go:

```
let hasQuestionsRemaining = user.numberOfCredits ?? 0.0 > 0.0
```

It'll treat `nil` values as `0.0` for the sake of comparison to `0.0`.