# Why can't Swift's greater-than or less-than operators compare optionals when the equality operators can?

Tags: swift, option-type

In Swift 3, this is a compile error, if I use `>` or `<`

```
let a: Int?
guard a > 0 else {return}
guard a < 0 else {return}
```

Compile error:

> Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

But it's okay if I compare with `==` or `!=`

```
let a: Int?
guard a == 0 else {return}
guard a != 0 else {return}
```

Comment: What would you expect `nil < 0` to evaluate to? How about `-1 < nil`? It's not clear how these cases should be treated. With `nil == 0`, it's perfectly clear what it means.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/39251005/2976878

Comment: Proposal: [Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md).  Also, this has to be a dupe.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427650/swift3-optionals-chaining-in-if-conditions-bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It makes perfect sense for the equality operator to support optionals, because it's absolutely clear that for any integer valued variable `i`:

- `nil == nil`
- `nil != i`
- `i != nil`
- `i == i` if and only if their values are the same

On the other hand, it's not clear how comparison to `nil` should act:

Is `i` less than `nil`?

- If I want to sort an array so that all the `nil`s come out at the end, then I would want `i` to be less than `nil`.
- But if I want to sort an array so that all the `nil`s come out at the start, then I would want `i` to be greater than `nil`.

Since either of these are equally valid, it wouldn't make sense for the standard library to favor one over the other. It's left to the programmer to implement whichever comparison makes sense for their use-case.

Here's a toy implementation that generates a comparison operator to suite either case:

```
func nilComparator<T: Comparable>(nilIsLess: Bool) -> (T?, T?) -> Bool {
    return {
        switch ($0, $1) {
            case (nil, nil): return false
            case (nil, _?): return nilIsLess
            case (_?, nil): return !nilIsLess
            case let (a?, b?): return a < b
        }
    }
}

let input = (0...10).enumerated().map {
    $0.offset.isMultiple(of: 2) ? Optional($0.element) : nil
}

func concisePrint<T>(_ optionals: [T?]) -> String {
    return "[" + optionals.map { $0.map{ "\($0)?" } ?? "nil" }.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
}

print("Input:", concisePrint(input))
print("nil is less:", concisePrint(input.sorted(by: nilComparator(nilIsLess: true))))
print("nil is more:", concisePrint(input.sorted(by: nilComparator(nilIsLess: false))))
```

Output:

> Input: `[0?, nil, 2?, nil, 4?, nil, 6?, nil, 8?, nil, 10?]`
>
> nil is less:  `[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 0?, 2?, 4?, 6?, 8?, 10?]`
>
> nil is more:  `[0?, 2?, 4?, 6?, 8?, 10?, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`

Answer (score 2):

Optional equality works logically, comparison doesn't.

- `5 == 5 = true`
- `5 == nil = false`
- `5 == 6 = false`
- `nil == nil = true`

Those all make sense, but these don't:

- `6 > 5 = true`
- `5 > 5 = false`
- `5 > nil = ??`
- `nil > 5 = ??`

This type of comparison does not have a simple answer, nor will that answer be the same depending on the use case.

Comment: `5 > nil = nil`
`nil > 5 = nil`

I'd expect return type in that case to be Bool?, not Bool

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Int` and `Int?` are 2 different things.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/integer_operators), `Int` has overloads for `<` and `>` and some other operators, while Optional only has overloads for `==` and `!=`, see the [documentation on Optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional#topics), the section talking about *Comparing Optional Values*.