# Swift sorted by error: Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat?' to expected argument type 'Self'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

This is the custom object:

```
struct ScannedFacts {
    var result = -1
    var frame:CGRect? = nil
    var name = ""
}
```

and this is the function in which i wanted to sort an array of the below kind:

```
func getSortedData(data:[(String, ScannedFacts)]) -> [(String, ScannedFacts)] {
    return data.sorted(by: {$0.1.frame?.minX < $1.1.frame?.minX})
}
```

this is the error i get which i really can't figure out:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat?' to expected argument type 'Self'
```

what am i missing out here?

Comment: Don't use `-1`, `""`, etc. as dummy values to mean "no value". That's what `nil` is for. For one, what happens when you *actually* have a `-1` result?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44808391/3141234 My `nilComparator` is exactly what can solve your problem, without all the bugs/errors associated with picking default values to stand-in for `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frame` property in `ScannedFact` is optional, hence you might wanna provide a default value when there isn't any frame available or when the frame property is `nil`. You cannot sort two objects comparing `nil`, so you either need to unwrap or give default values, like this:

```
func getSortedData(data:[(String, ScannedFacts)]) -> [(String, ScannedFacts)] {
    return data.sorted(by: {$0.1.frame?.minX ?? 0 < $1.1.frame?.minX ?? 0 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CGFloat` instead of `CGFloat?` when comparing values:

To make it easier you can use a computed property:

```
struct ScannedFacts {
    var frame:CGRect? = nil

    var frameMinX: CGFloat {
        // assume we treat `nil` the same way as `0`
        frame?.minX ?? 0
    }
}
```

```
return data.sorted { $0.1.frameMinX < $1.1.frameMinX }
```

Comment: Correcting myself, this is not compiling: var frameMinX: CGFloat: {
        frame?.minX ?? 0
    }

Comment: @Itzik984 Comparing optionals were removed in Swift 3: [Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md). This means you can only use unwrapped optionals unless you create your own extension.

Comment: @pawello2222 Don't hide optionals behind default values, because you're defeaing the *entire* point of optionals, which is to give consumers of an API several convenient options to decide for themselves exactly how they want to handle `nil`. `?? 0` might be one way, but force unwrapping, using a different value, propagating `nil`, etc. are all valid options. Don't take a way a callers ability to choose. How do you know if `frameMinX == 0` means "a non-nil value, whose values is actually actually 0", and "nil".

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I agree. I've just shown one way to do it. A computed property is a *convenience* method for *this* use case.

Comment: @pawello2222 I think you should clearly communicate that caveat, otherwise people are going to get the wrong idea. We don't know much about this use-case. Your code implicitly encodes a decision that `0` is representative of `nil`, and that `nil` and true `0` should be in the middle of the sort order, which is quite strange.