# Comparing two Doubles in Swift: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: ios, swift, double

I have a function that must check if a value (realOperand) is bigger than other value (realValue). These values are numeric, but they come in string, and I parse them to Double:

```
return Double(realOperand) > Double(realValue)
```

I can't understand why, but that line is giving this error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: @Larme as i writte in the question, two values that comes in String and I parse to doubles...

Comment: Both `Double(realOperand)` and `Double(realValue)` are optionals, so you need to unwrap them

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44808567/3141234

Comment: Larme, aheze, Alexander, one of you should post your info about optionals as an answer. That is clearly the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

`Double.init(_ string: String)` returns an Optional (Type `Double?`).

It would be like you wrote this code:

```
var a: Double? = nil
var b: Double? = 7

if a > b {
    print("A is greater")
}
```

Is nil greater than or less than 7? It's undefined. `Optional`s are not `Comparable`.

You need to decide what to do if either or both strings can't be converted to Double:

```
guard let operand = Double(realOperand),
  value = Double(realValue) else {
    // Crash on purpose. Not a great option for user-entered Strings!
    fatalError("Could not convert strings to Doubles")
}

return operand > value
```

Comment: thanks, but instead of doing a guard let i used !=nil and ! for force unwrap. Bytheway great explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can override the operator for comparing. Optional value.

As explained more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44808567/14733292) you can not compare optional values.

```
func > <T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs {
        return lhs > rhs
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```